# DataTable with button, append element to list

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the datatables plugin from jquery and I have added to my datatable a button. When pressing the button I would like to add the elements title to an  unordered list element.

Find below my minimum viable example:

```js
const results = {
  "generalInfo": [{
      "title": "title1",
      "permalink": "www.link.com",
      "manufacturer": "manufacturer1",
      "img": "https://images-na.ssl-images-test.com/images/asdfIdR/5adf1vELadfZeiMML.jpg",
      "curreny": "$",
      "price": "64.00",
      "availability": "Usually ships in 24 hours",
    },
    {
      "title": "title2",
      "permalink": "www.link.com",
      "manufacturer": "manufacturer2",
      "img": "https://images-na.ssl-images-test.com/images/I/51adfkLhadsfgACH0L.jpg",
      "curreny": "$",
      "price": "59.99",
      "availability": "Usually ships in 24 hours",
    }
  ]
}

//transform data set
let dataSet = results.generalInfo.map((item, i) => [
  i + 1,
  `<img src="${item.img}" alt="${item.title}" height="42" width="42">
                 <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                     ${item.title}
                 </a>`,
  item.manufacturer,
  `<div>${item.currency} ${item.price}</div>`,
  item.availability,
  `<button id="addButton" type="button" onClick="${this.addToResults.bind(item)}">
                    Add
                </button>`,
  `<a class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" role="button">
                    Buy
                </a>`
])

$('#table_id').DataTable({
  data: dataSet,
  destroy: true,
  columns: [{
      title: "#"
    },
    {
      title: "Title"
    },
    {
      title: "Manufacturer"
    },
    {
      title: "Price"
    },
    {
      title: "Availability"
    },
    {
      title: ""
    },
    {
      title: ""
    }
  ]
})

function addToResults(item) {

  $("ul").append(`<li>${item.title}</li>`);

}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="table_id" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>

<h1>Results:</h1>
<ul>

</ul>
```

When I press the button I get the an error message and the text is not appended.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding the item to your inline JS handler (which I really discourage people from doing, because inline JS is just plain bad), what you actually want is simply a reference back to the `results.generalInfo` array so that you can pull the correct item out from it.

In that case, this should suffice:

1. Assign a class, not an ID (IDs must be unique) to your button, say `<button class="addButton" ... />`.
2. Store an unchanging reference to the item in question. This is as simple as storing the index in the `data-` attribute, e.g. `<button data-item-index="${i}" class="addButton" ... />`
3. Bind a click event handler to that class
4. In the click event handler, retrieve the value from `data-item-index` and use it as a key to access the original item found in `results.generalInfo`. Remember that `data-` attributes always return string , so use the `+` operate to force cast it to an integer:

   ```
   $('#table_id').on('click', 'button.addButton', function() {
     const itemIndex = +$(this).data('item-index');
     const item = results.generalInfo[itemIndex];
     $("ul").append(`<li>${item.title}</li>`);
   });
   ```

See proof-of-concept snippet below:

```js
const results = {
  "generalInfo": [{
      "title": "title1",
      "permalink": "www.link.com",
      "manufacturer": "manufacturer1",
      "img": "https://images-na.ssl-images-test.com/images/asdfIdR/5adf1vELadfZeiMML.jpg",
      "curreny": "$",
      "price": "64.00",
      "availability": "Usually ships in 24 hours",
    },
    {
      "title": "title2",
      "permalink": "www.link.com",
      "manufacturer": "manufacturer2",
      "img": "https://images-na.ssl-images-test.com/images/I/51adfkLhadsfgACH0L.jpg",
      "curreny": "$",
      "price": "59.99",
      "availability": "Usually ships in 24 hours",
    }
  ]
}

//transform data set
let dataSet = results.generalInfo.map((item, i) => [
  i + 1,
  `<img src="${item.img}" alt="${item.title}" height="42" width="42">
                 <a href="#">
                     ${item.title}
                 </a>`,
  item.manufacturer,
  `<div>${item.currency} ${item.price}</div>`,
  item.availability,
  `<button class="addButton" type="button" data-item-index="${i}">
                    Add
                </button>`,
  `<a class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" role="button">
                    Buy
                </a>`
]);

$('#table_id').on('click', 'button.addButton', function() {
  const item = results.generalInfo[+$(this).data('item-index')];
  $("ul").append(`<li>${item.title}</li>`);
});

$('#table_id').DataTable({
  data: dataSet,
  destroy: true,
  columns: [{
      title: "#"
    },
    {
      title: "Title"
    },
    {
      title: "Manufacturer"
    },
    {
      title: "Price"
    },
    {
      title: "Availability"
    },
    {
      title: ""
    },
    {
      title: ""
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="table_id" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>

<h1>Results:</h1>
<ul>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thx for the answer! Is there also a way to pass the whole item to the click-listener directly via the function call on the click listener?

Comment: @mrquad The whole item is already assigned to the `item` constant in the click handler.

Comment: One final question, why did you put the on-click listener on the table instead of putting it directly on the button. Such as, `$('#table_id')` instead of `$('.addButton')` Thx in advance for your comment!

Comment: @mrquad It's actually to capture event bubbling. Since you have the button added dynamically to the table, you cannot bind a click event directly to the buttons, because they are not available at runtime. Instead, you bind the click event on the table itself, and simply checks if the click event has *bubbled up* from a button element (hence the second argument of the `.on()` method).